# Как определять заполнение формы после перехода с рекламы?

Tags: php, google-adwords

Есть сайт с онлайн формой. После заполнения формы на почту приходит письмо с данными из формы. Как можно реализовать добавление в текст письма параметров с реферером перехода клиента?

Например, если переход был с рекламы Google Adwords, в приходящем письме указывалось бы, что форма отправлена после перехода с рекламы.

Comment: Добавьте в форму скрытое поле с $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас переход может быть на любую страницу сайта и там нет формы, то лучше данные из `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` записать в сессию или куки, при этом не забывайте отмечать, чтобы переход был из внешнего источника, а далее уже можете либо в скрытый инпут добавить параметр, либо (что лучше) прямо во врем отправки письма проверять на наличие значения и добавлять к письму это значение.